# Running simple Qt GUI application in Go

Tags: qt, user-interface, go

I am trying to modify following simple code from [here](https://doc.qt.io/archives/3.3/tutorial1-01.html) to use Qt in Go.

```
#include <qapplication.h>
#include <qpushbutton.h>
int main( int argc, char **argv )
{
    QApplication a( argc, argv );

    QPushButton hello( "Hello world!", 0 );
    hello.resize( 100, 30 );

    a.setMainWidget( &hello );
    hello.show();
    return a.exec();
}
```

My [Go (Golang)](https://golang.org/) code is:

```
package main
import (
    "github.com/therecipe/qt"
    "github.com/therecipe/qt/widgets"
)
func main() {
    a := qt.NewQApplication(len(os.Args), os.Args) //ch: widgets.NewQ..
    hello := widgets.QPushButton( "Hello world!", 0 )
    a.setMainWidget( &hello )
    hello.Show()
    a.Exec()
}
```

However, I get following error:

```
# github.com/therecipe/qt/core
core.cpp:9:30: fatal error: QAbstractAnimation: No such file or directory
 #include <QAbstractAnimation>
                              ^
compilation terminated.
```

I have installed Qt bindings in Go using command:

```
go get "github.com/therecipe/qt"
```

I am working on Debian9 Linux and have following Qt4 packages installed:

```
libntrack-qt4-1         016-1.3         016-1.3         016-1.3         install
libqt4-dev              4:4.8.7+dfsg-11 4:4.8.7+dfsg-11 4:4.8.7+dfsg-11 install
libqt4-dev-bin          4:4.8.7+dfsg-11 4:4.8.7+dfsg-11 4:4.8.7+dfsg-11 install
libqt4-opengl-dev       4:4.8.7+dfsg-11 4:4.8.7+dfsg-11 4:4.8.7+dfsg-11 install
python-qt4              4.11.4+dfsg-2+b1        4.11.4+dfsg-2+b1        4.11.4+dfsg-2+b1        install
qt4-default             4:4.8.7+dfsg-11 4:4.8.7+dfsg-11 4:4.8.7+dfsg-11 install
qt4-linguist-tools      4:4.8.7+dfsg-11 4:4.8.7+dfsg-11 4:4.8.7+dfsg-11 install
qt4-qmake               4:4.8.7+dfsg-11 4:4.8.7+dfsg-11 4:4.8.7+dfsg-11 install
ruby-qt4                4:4.14.3-1+b3   4:4.14.3-1+b3   4:4.14.3-1+b3   install
```

Where is the problem and how can it be solved? Thanks for your help.

Edit: For installing, I followed commands at https://github.com/therecipe/qt/wiki/Installation-on-Linux [Your system package managers version (without Android support)]. However, the command qtsetup gives following output with error:

```
$ sudo /home/abcde/go/bin/qtsetup
ERRO[0000] failed to run command                         _func=RunCmd cmd="go env GOMOD" dir= env= error="exec: \"go\": executable file not found in $PATH" name=GOMOD
```

Comment: Hi, from the github wiki of therecipe/qt, it seems to expect Qt5 and not Qt4: https://github.com/therecipe/qt/wiki/Installation-on-Linux

Comment: @Dinesh : I installed `sudo apt-get --no-install-recommends install libqt*5-dev qt*5-dev qml-module-qtquick-* ` but error is persisting. This command (part of installation) is not working: `$(go env GOPATH)/bin/qtsetup`

Comment: What's the error you're getting? did qtsetup get installed correctly?

Comment: I have added output and error of qtsetup command in my question above.

Comment: The error says it all no? It can't find go executable in your PATH. Something is off with your go installation.

Comment: Go is otherwise working all right. I had downloaded and installed with command `tar -C /usr/local -xzf go$VERSION.$OS-$ARCH.tar.gz` as given on https://golang.org/doc/install . Can I correct above error?

Comment: Out of curiosity, why are you using sudo to run qtsetup? If you followed the go lang installations as per their website and added `export PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/go/bin`  to your `/home/abcde/.profile`, it won't be accessible to qtsetup because sudo makes it look for .profile in `/root/.profile`. If you want to use sudo, add the path to `/etc/profile` . Or don't use sudo

Comment: Without sudo, it did not work since it was trying to make symlinks in sbin folder.

Comment: Ah well add the `/usr/local/go/bin` to  `/etc/profile` . The qtsetup probably assumed you've installed go to /home/abcde/bin/go or some such paths.

Comment: It does not work. I am abandoning it currently. As such therecipe/qt takes 1.1Gb disk space which is in addition to what Qt packages take on Debian installation.